# How to change the font of mathematical symbols in TeXstudio?

Tags: fonts, symbols

When using TeXstudio I always got very nice mathmatical symbols, for example the integral sign was the slightly slanting one used in the English literature.
Now I reinstalled MiKTeK and TeXstudio, but the rendering of mathematics is not that good. Mathematical symbols look old and they come with some problems (for example applying an exponent and a vector sign on a letter results in an unreadble overlap of the two).
How to solve?

[image: This is an example of how symbols look like in now (above) and how I want them to look like (below)]

Comment: TeXstudio has nothing to do with your fonts or how they render on the PDF output, check the loaded packages and what font settings they may change. BTW, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Could you show us the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to reproduce your output (with just the fix of `\,` in front of the differential):

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{\delta t\to 0} K \int \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (K\,dx_j)
\]

\end{document}
```

As soon as I remove `\usepackage{mathabx}` I get

[image]

Thus the answer is: don't use `mathabx`.